# How to calculate Elapsed Duration with DateTime

Tags: c#, time, kinect

I have a question. In this code, one-step time and cycle time are calculated as 0. It does not calculate the second before a minute has elapsed. However, when it is 1 minute, it calculates the minute. But we want it to be calculated separately. Where are we making mistakes?

One minute is completed in 30 seconds, it has to be 1 minute in 60 seconds.

StepPerMinute should only respond if it completes for a min otherwise it should fall into the cath block but I'm having a problem.

AStepDuration must be calculated every second, but after 1 minute the calculation starts before it returns zero.

Cycle time always gives zero.

```
if (stepCount == 1)
{
    firstStepTime = DateTime.Now;
}
else if (stepCount > 1)
{
    DateTime stepTime = DateTime.Now;
    var result = stepTime.Subtract(firstStepTime);
    var totalMinutes = Convert.ToInt16(result.TotalMinutes);
    totalSeconds = Convert.ToInt16(result.TotalSeconds);

    try
    {
        stepsPerMinute = Convert.ToInt16(stepCount / totalMinutes);
        AStepDuration = (Convert.ToDouble( totalSeconds ) / stepCount);
        CycleTime = totalSeconds * (2 / stepCount); 
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException)
    {
      stepsPerMinute = stepCount;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0}", totalMinutes+"dk");
    Console.WriteLine("Total second : {0}", totalSeconds+"sn");
    Console.WriteLine("Steps Per Minute(Cadence): {0}", stepsPerMinute +"step/min");
    Console.WriteLine("A Step Duration: {0}", AStepDuration);
    Console.WriteLine("Cycle Time: {0}", CycleTime + "sn");
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you mean by "it does not calculate the second before a minute has elapsed". It would be much easier to help you if you could provide a [mcve]. (As an aside, I'd also strongly recommend that you check for zero as a divisor, rather than catching DivideByZeroException.)

Comment: Also, look over your types to make sure you're not doing unnecessary casting / converting. For example, `result.TotalSeconds` is a double, but you're converting to a `Short`, just to immediately convert back to a double.

Comment: A side effect of all that unnecessary converting is that you're probably ending up with integer division.

Comment: @JonSkeet It starts calculating a step duration(BirAdİmSüresi) only after one minute has elapsed. It needs to be calculated in seconds, but it always gives me the result 0 before 1 minute is up.
I do not fully understand your suggestion. How should I write the Dividedbyzeroexception. Can you show it in the sample code?

Comment: No, because I'm afraid the whole purpose of the code is too unclear at the moment. Again, I would strongly recommend that you create a [mcve] and read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for advice on writing a good question. (I'd also suggest making sure that all variable names are in English for the purpose of your Stack Overflow question - but you may well find that you don't need all the variables that you currently have anyway.)

Comment: Hi @kubraCelebi did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that Kinect has `StopWatch` but, if it is available then you may use it like this instead of using `DateTime`.

```
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    // you may stop like this stopWatch.Stop()
    // or reset like this stopWatch.Reset()
    if (stepCount == 1)
    {
        stopWatch.Start();
    }
    else if (stepCount > 1)
    {
        try
        {
            stepsPerMinute = Convert.ToInt16(stepCount / stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes);
            BirAdimSüresi = (Convert.ToDouble(stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds) / stepCount);
            CycleTime = stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds * (2 / stepCount); // saniye or CycleTime =120/ cadence

        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            stepsPerMinute = stepCount;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0}", stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes + "dk");
        Console.WriteLine("Total seconds : {0}", stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds + "sn");
        Console.WriteLine("Steps Per Minute(Cadence): {0}", stepsPerMinute + "step/min");
        Console.WriteLine("Bir Adim Süresi: {0}", BirAdimSüresi);
        Console.WriteLine("Cycle Time: {0}", CycleTime + "sn");
    }
```